# How to know if someone else handled OnContextMenu

Tags: mfc, winapi, contextmenu, window-messages

I have a `CWnd` derived class that has a `WM_CONTEXTMENU` handler (`OnContextMenu`), which  has my default context menu.  This class is being used at several places in my application.

Some of the places where it's being used also handle the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` at the parent level (the window parent).  They basically override the default context menu.

When I am inside the `CWnd` derived class, I basically want to know if someone else (a window parent) handled the context menu.

for example:

```
void MyDerivedWnd::OnContextMenu( CWnd* in_pWnd, CPoint in_point )
{
    LRESULT res = __super::Default();

    // Now, how to I know of something happened inside __super::Default();??

    // Show my default menu
    // ...
}
```

It is possible via the Win32/MFC framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to discover if something happened during the default handler implementation.  It may not be the most elegant solution, but here it is:

```
bool g_bWindowCreated = false;
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( code == HCBT_CREATEWND )
        g_bWindowCreated = true;

    return CallNextHookEx( g_hHook, code, wParam, lParam );
}

void MyDerivedWnd::OnContextMenu( CWnd* in_pWnd, CPoint in_point )
{
    // Setup a hook to know if a window was created during the 
    // Default WM_CONTEXT_MENU handler
    g_bWindowCreated = false;
    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, HookProc, NULL,  GetCurrentThreadId() );

    // Call the default handler
    LRESULT res = __super::Default();

    UnhookWindowsHookEx( g_hHook );

    if( !g_bWindowCreated )
    {
        // Show my default menu
        // ...
    }
}
```